# Getting Issue in expo locaton

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoModulesCore.NativeModulesProxy.ExpoLocation')

i want to use expo location but getting this issue after importing expo locaation in component

````
 node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
 node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
 node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
 node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
 node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
 node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
 node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
 node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
 node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
 node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:29 in invoke
 node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
 node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:155:27 in invoke
 node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:165:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
 node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
 node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
 node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
 node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
 node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
 node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
 node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
 node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
 node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
 [native code]:null in flushedQueue
 [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue```
````

Comment: Can you show me the error code part?

Comment: I did not write code to get the current location but when I import the expo location this error is shown (evaluating '_expoModulesCore.NativeModulesProxy.ExpoLocation)

Comment: could you read this ?? https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/

Comment: yes, I read this. and I am using the expo CLI project.